# SWIFT: use UIWebkit View

Tags: ios, swift

im trying to use the UI WebKit View.

I created a single view app, placed a UI WebKit View on the main View and put the constraints "centering horizontally and vertically in container, fixed height and equal width to superview" to it.

then i changed my ViewController.swift to

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myUrl = URL(string: "www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But when i start the app i get only a blank screen. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url is not valid so change this

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "www.apple.com")
```

to

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
```